# Use python PGSQL driver without installing it?

Tags: python, postgresql, psql

Is there anyway I can use any pgsql driver without actually installing it? I see `Psycopg2` is most commonly used for connecting to PGSQL database but that need installing and The issue I have here is I need to distribute the code but the we are not allowed to install anything on the server. Anything standalone (e.g. including the driver/library files in a directory along with my scripts) but that's the only thing I can do. Is there any way I can `import` psycopg2 from a local directory?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anyone care to explain the reason for down-voting me? As member of SO (whoever you are), where we are learning something new everyday, should have the minimum courtesy (and sense) to other fellow members to explain what mistake or wrong-doing have been done here for giving negative  :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can import modules from local files - you can even import whole python files of your own if you want. You can download the [source code](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2?files=1) and put it onto your system by using a USB stick (if permitted). However, you [will still have to install it](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/doc/src/install.rst) which may not be possible depending on your situation. If this is for homework or a school project, I recommend only using files or libraries you create or are provided with. 
You can read more about Python imports here https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html Best of luck.

Comment: Too old for homework. This is for 'work', to help support team to run some queries without login into production database.